# CMD.ExecuteScalar() returns 0 on stored procedure to insert data

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I have an assignment where I have to create a database and an application to run a store. The assignment is almost finished, just need to fix this part of the code. The problem is that I don't know what the error is. I have a stored procedure to insert clients into the database:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE Projeto.Add_newClient 
    (@NIF BIGINT, 
     @Address VARCHAR(40), 
     @Name VARCHAR(20), 
     @Phone BIGINT) 
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Projeto.Cliente WHERE Cliente.NIF = @NIF)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('The client with NIF %I64i already exists', 14, 1, @NIF);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Projeto.Cliente (NIF, Morada, Nome, NumTelem)
        VALUES (@NIF, @Address, @Name, @Phone);
    END
GO
```

When I test it in SQL Server Management Studio, it works just fine and does exactly what it is supposed to do.

Then I have to use this stored procedure in the application and I do it like this:

```vb
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    If NIFTextBox.Text.Length <> 9 Then
        MsgBox("Client's NIF Must Have 9 Numbers!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ERROR")
    ElseIf NameTextBox.Text.Equals("") Then
        MsgBox("Please Insert Client's Name!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ERROR")
    ElseIf PhoneTextBox.Text.Length <> 9 Then
        MsgBox("Client's Phone Number Must Have 9 Numbers!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ERROR")
    Else
        Dim NIF As Integer = NIFTextBox.Text
        Dim name As String = NameTextBox.Text
        Dim address As String = AddressTextBox.Text
        Dim phone As Integer = PhoneTextBox.Text
        addClient(NIF, address, name, phone)
        NIFTextBox.Text = ""
        NameTextBox.Text = ""
        AddressTextBox.Text = ""
        PhoneTextBox.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

`addClient` has the following code:

```vb
Private Sub addClient(ByVal NIF As Integer, ByVal address As String, ByVal name As String, ByVal phone As Integer)
    CMD = New SqlCommand()
    CMD.Connection = CN
    CMD.CommandText = "EXEC Projeto.Add_newClient @NIF, @Address, @Name, @Phone"
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@NIF", SqlDbType.BigInt)
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40)
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.BigInt)
    CMD.Parameters("@NIF").Value = NIF
    CMD.Parameters("@Address").Value = address
    CMD.Parameters("@Name").Value = name
    CMD.Parameters("@Phone").Value = phone
    Dim NIFbool As Boolean = checkNIF(NIF)
    Dim PhoneBool As Boolean = checkPhone(phone)
    If (NIFbool = True And PhoneBool = True) Then
        CN.Open()
        Dim test As Object = CMD.ExecuteScalar()
        MessageBox.Show(test)
        loadClients()
        CN.Close()
    ElseIf (NIFbool = False And PhoneBool = True) Then
        MsgBox("The NIF inserted already exists!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ERROR")
    ElseIf (NIFbool = True And PhoneBool = False) Then
        MsgBox("The Phone number inserted already exists!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ERROR")
    Else
        MsgBox("The NIF and Phone number inserted already exists!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ERROR")
    End If
End Sub
```

`NIFBool` and `PhoneBool` are just variables to check if those phone or NIF already exist, and those are working fine.

My problem is that when I run the application, I fill in the text boxes, press the button and nothing happens. The client is not added to the database and the application does not crash. I added the variable `test` to see what was the result of `ExecuteScalar()`. Since it is an insertion, the result should be Null. However, the result is always 0. I used many other stored procedures and this is the only place where this happens.

Does anyone know what can is causing this issue?

EDIT: link to repository with full code https://github.com/tiagoadonis/MTsSportsLine

EDIT2: apparently the boolean variables `NIFBool` and `PhoneBool` were in the wrong place of the code, that verification was being done at the sime time as the stored prcedure should be executed. By moving them up in the code it works fine now

Comment: ExecuteScalar() is for batches that return a resultset.  That procedure does not.  You should use ExecuteNonQuery() instead.

Comment: I did, it returns -1 and still does not add anything to the database but also does not crash

Comment: Then troubleshoot in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: The problem is not in the procedure code, I tested it in SQL Management Studio and it works fine. The problem seems to be in the VB code, the interaction with the stored procedure, I just can't figure out where. Mainly because it should return Null instead of a value. And since the procedure works fine when tested in SQL, the problem has to be in the VB code

Comment: SQL Profiler or an Extended Events Session can trace all the database calls and you can see what's going on.  Other than that you'll need to post a complete repro.  That code looks fine.

Comment: I will try that, thank you!

Comment: This is what shows up when I try to execute the procedure but I have no idea what it means. Does it mean that it is not executing the procedure? https://imgur.com/VlTvgj1

Comment: Yes.  It is not executing the procedure.  So either the VB code isn't running, or it's connected so some other database server.

Comment: The connection is being defined on the top of the page and many other procedures on that page are being executed correctly so it can't have anything to do with the connection. As far as the VB code goes, the variable `test` assigned to the result of the procedure is returning a value so the code is running. I see no reason why the procedure is not being executed

Comment: Then copy that code out into a new standalone app.  If the behavior is reproducible, post the code in your question.

Comment: I have tried it and got the same results. I have edited the post with the repository link so that you can see the code, as it is a bit extense to fully post in here

Comment: Then simplify it.  You'll probably find your bug in the process.

Comment: It is as simple as it can be, I need to apply all of the things taught during the semester so the code by itself has some extent but it is not complicated at all. I just don't understand why everything else in the project i working except for that, even though I did it the exact same way as all of the other procedures

Comment: Learning to debug is part of the process.  Trust that there's a reason.  You just have to find it.

Comment: I have been trying to debug this since Tuesday and still got nothing, that is why I am asking for help

Comment: `CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ' in your case. Also, you need to use `ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: @evry1falls thank you for the reply. I just tried it but sadly did not work

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime. I downloaded your code from GitHub and it lite up like a Christmas tree. These issues need to be corrected.

I question the `bigint` for `NIF` and `phone`. A nine digit number will easily fit in int (+ or - 2 trillion). Also, I don't know how you fit an address into 40 characters.

Why are you using `checkNIF` when you have built this into your stored procedure? Why not add the phone check to the stored procedure with an `Or` in the `Where` clause of the `Select`? Then get rid of both of the check methods. This would be preferable to multiple hits on the database.

Keep your connection local to the method where it is used. This way you can be sure it is closed and disposed with `Using...End Using` blocks. Here the command is also included in the block.

```vb
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Dim NIF As Integer
    Dim phone As Integer
    If NIFTextBox.Text.Length <> 9 AndAlso Not Integer.TryParse(NIFTextBox.Text, NIF) Then
        MsgBox("Client's NIF Must Have 9 Numbers!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ERROR")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf NameTextBox.Text.Equals("") Then
        MsgBox("Please Insert Client's Name!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ERROR")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf PhoneTextBox.Text.Length <> 9 AndAlso Not Integer.TryParse(PhoneTextBox.Text, phone) Then
        MsgBox("Client's Phone Number Must Have 9 Numbers!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ERROR")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    addClient(NIF, AddressTextBox.Text, NameTextBox.Text, phone)
End Sub

Private Sub addClient(ByVal NIF As Integer, ByVal address As String, ByVal name As String, ByVal phone As Integer)
    Dim RetVal As Integer
    Using CN As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            CMD As New SqlCommand("Add_newClient", CN)
        CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@NIF", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = NIF
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = address
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = name
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = phone
        CN.Open()
        RetVal = CMD.ExecuteNonQuery() 'This returns number of records affected
    End Using
    If RetVal = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Successful Insert")
        ClearTextBoxes()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error inserting data")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ClearTextBoxes()
    NIFTextBox.Text = ""
    NameTextBox.Text = ""
    AddressTextBox.Text = ""
    PhoneTextBox.Text = ""
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Surround the last line of the button click event with a Try block

```
    Try
        addClient(NIF, AddressTextBox.Text, NameTextBox.Text, phone)
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! Just tried your solution and still got the same results, sadly. `ExecuteNonQuery()` still retuns -1. As to the why of using `bigint` for `NIF` and `phone`, my teachers told me to. I am using `checkNIF` because, even though that verification is already being done in the stored procedure, if I did not have that function, the application would crash, showing the error raised in the stored procedure. But I don't want it to crash, so I need to do the verification twice.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. See if you get any message.

Comment: Nothing, it throws no exception